jQuery beforeunload not working as expected
The implementation of this jQuery function drives me crazy!!!
I know there are a lot of articles about it and I have spend hours to read them, but could not find any useful solution!
I created a simple chat and need a function to clear the user from the active user list, if he close the window. I don't want to send any message only have the possibility clear something up before closing.
So the only way I have figured out yet, is using the beforeunload, but this is not working for my use case.
Here my code:
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
    alert('beforeunload');
    $('#crMode').val('close');
    $('#chat').submit();
    return undefined;
});


The alert and the other 2 instructions seem to be ignored by Firefox and Chrome.
If the user has done nothing with the window, the message will not send.
But when I press Ctrl F5 always a message appears!

So how to can solve my simple problem, to kill the user before he left the chat?

You can't do most things in a beforeunload event handler. Spammers took that away from us. So no form submissions, no ajax, I don't believe you can even do anything with sockets... Speaking of sockets, you could be sending a "keepalive" ping that times a user out if not responded to...

Fortunately there is no way to guarantee that any Javascript fully executes before a user closes a page.

The only purpose of beforeunload is to cause the confirmation dialogue that asks the user if they really want to navigate away from the page.
